# jQuery get YouTube video title

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube

I'm trying to use jQuery to get a YouTube videos title from the YouTube API with a JSON object, the issue in having is that all of the URLs to get the JSON object from the YouTube API are not returning the correct video details. It is always returning a googledevicehelp video or something. If someone is able to give me th correct URL I'd appreciate it the latest one I tested was

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/(the-video-id)?v=2&alt=json

And it's still not returning the video details

Comment: It's probably because you're not using the API correctly. show your code.

Comment: Check the examples in the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters) - You probably need to provide a key when requesting data. Yet, without more information it's difficult to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube API (v2) is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries?csw=1) - Use this link to retrieve the title (you'll need API key):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

More info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: Using that will expose the API Key to everybody right ?

Comment: @L01c yes, everybody will be able to see it in the Developer Tools

Comment: @L01c Google API console enables API key protection to be used by certain referrals, this will protect your API from others by just setting your domain name, so the key is visible but not accessible by others.